# React two contexts at the same time

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm messing around with `context` in React and I'm wondering if there is a way to consume 2 context in the same class with the `static` way. I know I can do it with 2 consumers and accesing their value returning a function like the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts) says, but I want to access both context in the whole class like it is done with `static contextType = HomeContext`. Is there a way to do something like this?:

```
FormControl.contextType = {
  HomeContext,
  FormContext
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple context can't be accessed using the `contextType` Api. Instead you need to make use of Render props pattern

```
<HomeContext.Consumer>
   {(homeContext) => (
      <FormContext.Consumer>
         {(formContext) => (
             <YourComponent homeContext={homeContext} formContext={formContext} />
         )}
      </FormContext.Consumer>
   )}
</HomeContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I can access 1 using the `contextType` and the rest use it like the render props pattern.